# Sum dict values under the same key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of items and values:

`users_lst = ['    spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora:      22.1\n', '\n', 'applemusic: \n]`

I want to convert it to a dictionary, like this:

`users = {'spotify': 50.4, 'pandora': 45.5}`

My current code doesn't sum up the values for pandora:

```
users_lst = ['spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora: 22.1\n']

for i in users_lst:
  i = i.split(':')
  key = i[0]
  value = i[1]

  users[key] = value

print(users) #output: {'spotify': ' 50.4\n', 'applemusic': ' 22.1\n'}
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated! Prefer to use a solution without importing modules.

*Edit: updated the list to include non-float-type, blank and leading/trailing space cases

Comment: You need to check the before to atribbute value. user[key] = user.get(key,0)+value. But value are as string need also to convert to int or float.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sum

Comment: Aren't values summed, in this case? Or how would you phrase this?

Answer (score 1):

I can use a simple for loop and bunch of string cleaning operations like this to solve the problem,

```
users_lst = ['spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora: 22.1\n']

d = dict()
for item in users_lst:
    key, val = item.split(":")
    val = float(val.strip().replace("\n", ""))
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = val
    else:
        d[key] = d[key] + val
        
        
print(d) # {'spotify': 50.4, 'pandora': 45.5}
```

You can use dict.get() method and eliminate the use of if else checks like this,

```
users_lst = ['spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora: 22.1\n']

d = dict()
for item in users_lst:
    key, val = item.split(":")    
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + float(val)
        
        
print(d) # {'spotify': 50.4, 'pandora': 45.5}
```

Comment: users_lst = ['  spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora:       22.1\n'. '\n', 'applemusic: \n]  --> Thanks for the solution! Is there a way to make the above solution work for this list?

Comment: ['    spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora:      22.1\n', '\n', 'applemusic: \n]

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

users_lst = ['spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora: 22.1\n']
result = defaultdict(float)

for i in users_lst:
    key, value = i.strip().split(":")
    result[key] += float(value)
    
print(result)  # OR print(dict(result))
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'spotify': 50.4, 'pandora': 45.5})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is many way to do this:

```
users_lst = ['spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora: 22.1\n']

user = dict()
for item in users_lst:
    key, val = item.split(":")
    val = float(val.strip())
    user[key] = user.get(key,0)+value
```

Comment: There is no need for `.replace("\n", "")`, `strip()` makes the trick

Comment: @pbacterio That's correct I edited the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in users_lst:
  key, value = i.strip().split(':')
  users[key] = users.get(key, 0.0) + float(value)
```

Comment: users_lst = ['    spotify: 50.4\n', 'pandora: 23.4\n', 'pandora:      22.1\n', '\n', 'applemusic: \n]  ---> Thanks for the solution! Is there a way to make the above solution work for this list?